# Using image with text in navbar

Tags: html, css, jsp, web, frontend

I just started using HTML and CSS. And I need help.

I want to use images and also text(for the title) in my header. So I used navbar.

If I make my window smaller, I want the text to move with the image but it doesn't move at all.
I think it's because of `left: 480px;` in the code but if I don't use `left: 480px;`, it won't appear on the image.

Is there any way that it can move with the image when I make the window small?

FULL SIZE OF THE WINDOW
[image: FULL SIZE OF THE WINDOW]

WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE WHEN I MAKE THE WINDOW SIZE SMALLER
[image]

the text is in the middle with `left:480px;`. I want the text to keep placed on the left side.
Which part should I need to change or add to the code?

```css
.navbar {
  display: block;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 28px;
  font-family: NanumGothic;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 12.8px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  top: 50px;
  left: 480px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Change Member Info</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="frm" name="frm">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__logo">
          <img src="/assets/images/notext_title_04@3x.png">
          <span>My Website</span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use a relative position value, e.g. left: 30% instead of an absolute pixel value. That will make it somewhat responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try two ways to make this responsive

**1. Giving margin-left in percentages**

```
.navbar span{
            left: 30%
            }
```

This takes left spacing percentage in terms of screen size. So it adopts automatically

**2. Using Media Queries**

By using this you can set CSS specifically for different screen size

```
/* Set CSS for Full screen size */
.navbar span{
                left: 480px
                }


/* On screens that are 992px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar span{
                left: 380px
                }
}

/* On screens that are 600px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .navbar span{
                left: 300px
                }
}
```